# Obtain an reference to a wcf service

Tags: wcf

I have a wcf service singleton type, and in the same application an ASP page that uses a service-specific function.

As I can get a reference to the service instance created, not to run twice the manufacturer's service?

My service is published on IIS

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are saying that you have a service that is supposed to be a singleton and because you're in the same AppDomain you can simply create an instance as well.

If you own the service code you can make it a singleton using the Singleton Pattern (there are a number of ways to do that in .NET and Jon Skeet has a list of them [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)).

Then you need to deal with how does WCF get hold of the instance? In that case there are two options:

1. Use a [ServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory.aspx) and hand the instance to the ServiceHost you create
2. Implement [IInstanceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider.aspx) and plumb that in

If you don't control the service class then there is nothing you can do to prevent people creating instances but you can wrap the class in your own singleton and stipulate access must only be via the singleton so it is less likely that someone will create a second instance